# This project references NuGet packages that are missing on this computer (TFS)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm using TFS for the first time and attempting a build. I'm getting the error:

`This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. use NuGet Package Restore to download them.`

I realize that there are many similar posts on StackOverflow and I've searched through quite a few of them. What I've gathered is that the two boxes under Package Restore in Package Manager Settings should be checked (but that this is also irrelevant now because they're checked by default). I verified that mine were both checked anyway.

The next piece of advice I considered is deleting the /packages folder from the Source Control version of my application. There is no packages folder there OR in my local (pre migration to TFS) version of the application. Instead, there's a ../packages/ folder (up one level) from the application folder. It seems that, at some point, I've opted to store the packages for all of my applications in the same folder? If so, where is this setting and what do I need to change it to either in my local version or in Source Control Explorer?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if it isn't a bit more simple. Perhaps this can solve your issue - without answering all your questions. In Visual Studio with your solution open (.sln), in "Solution Explorer", right click on "Solution..." and select Restore NuGet Packages. Now rebuild and see whether you still have the same issue.

Comment: I attempted that and got a message that all packages were up to date. Attempted Rebuild and Build, same result.